# Best way (performance-wise) to iterate over a dictionary

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, iteration

[This](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/readability/not_using_items_to_iterate_over_a_dictionary.html)
suggests that `.items()` is the best way to iterate over a dictionary because it's pythonic.

Performance-wise, which of the below is the best and why?

1. ```
   for key in dic:
       value = dic[key]
   ```
2. ```
   for key, value in dic.items():
   ```
3. ```
   for key in dic.keys():
       value = dic[key]
   ```

Comment: Try all three yourself with `timeit`...?

Comment: First and third variants are in fact same, using them you can iterate over dict keys; second variant is used to iterate over keys and values at once. You can't find best, cause each has different purpose.

Comment: ... "and why"? @Dan

Comment: @OlvinRoght: Variant #3 will be ever-so-slightly slower, since it has to make an actual keys view object.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, that's why I've added "in fact" :) I've meant that both variants does same.

Comment: The point that link is trying to make is if you *want to iterate over the key-value **pairs** in a dict*, use `.items()`, but if you **only need the keys**, then `for key in my_dict:` is perfectly pythonic

Answer (score 2):

Based on timeit values :

To find keys and values,

```
from timeit import timeit

d = {i: i for i in range(100)}

def a():
    for key in d:
        d[key]
        pass

def b():
    for key, value in d.items():
        pass

def c():
    for key in d.keys():
        d[key]
        pass

for fn in [a, b, c]:
    print(fn.__name__, timeit(fn))


Solution 1 7.8113735559999995
Solution 2 2.6758934780000008
Solution 3 5.499667492
```

To just find the keys,

```
from timeit import timeit

d = {i: i for i in range(100)}

def a():
    for key in d:
        pass

def b():
    for key, value in d.items():
        pass

def c():
    for key in d.keys():
        pass

for fn in [a, b, c]:
    print(fn.__name__, timeit(fn))

Solution 1 1.5981329149999999
Solution 2 2.649033456
Solution 3 1.6517934609999996
```

So to find the keys the first solution is fastest, but to find the keys and values the second solution is fastest.

Comment: ... this is a good contribution but it isn't reproducible because you haven't posted your benchmarks

Answer (score 2):

These sorts of generic timings are rarely useful as performance is driven by a much wider array of variables specific to the data, application and environment in question, but for the sake of providing some simple comparison data here are a few tests that you can copy and try in your own environment.

Just iterating without accessing dict values unsurprisingly suggests that there is very little performance difference in any of the methods except for `dict.items()` running just slightly behind since it is creating a view of both keys and values (while the other methods shown are only dealing with one or the other).

```
from timeit import timeit

loop = """
d = dict(zip(range(1000), reversed(range(1000))))
for k in d: pass"""
print(timeit(stmt=loop, number=10000))
# 1.0733639170002789

keys = """
d = dict(zip(range(1000), reversed(range(1000))))
for k in d.keys(): pass"""
print(timeit(stmt=keys, number=10000))
# 1.0360493710004448

values = """
d = dict(zip(range(1000), reversed(range(1000))))
for v in d.values(): pass"""
print(timeit(stmt=values, number=10000))
# 1.0380961279997791

items = """
d = dict(zip(range(1000), reversed(range(1000))))
for v in d.items(): pass"""
print(timeit(stmt=items, number=10000))
# 1.2011308679993817
```

Iterating while accessing the value for each key in an attempt to level the playing field unsurprisingly suggests that `dict.items()` is slightly faster when you need to both iterate over and access keys and values.

```
from timeit import timeit

loop = """
d = dict(zip(range(1000), reversed(range(1000))))
for k in d: d[k]"""
print(timeit(stmt=loop, number=10000))
# 1.4128917540001567

keys = """
d = dict(zip(range(1000), reversed(range(1000))))
for k in d.keys(): d[k]"""
print(timeit(stmt=keys, number=10000))
# 1.3668724469998779

items = """
d = dict(zip(range(1000), reversed(range(1000))))
for v in d.items(): pass"""
print(timeit(stmt=items, number=10000))
# 1.1864945030001763
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need both keys and values, use `for k, v in mydict.items():`; iterating the keys and then looking it up means unnecessarily looking up information you could have gotten for free with `.items()`. For *very* short `dict`s, it might be slower than `for k in mydict:` followed by lookup (simply because there is a very small cost to creating the items view that may exceed that of a few lookups), but for `dict`s of moderate length, `.items()` will always win.

If you only need the keys, both `for k in mydict:` and `for k in mydict.keys():` are roughly identical, though the latter is a tiny bit slower in Py3 (due to needing to construct the keys view) and can be significantly slower on Py2 (where it makes a temporary `list` with a copy of the keys, where the former approach lazily iterates the `dict` directly).

Answer (score -1):

Two is your best option for two reasons,

1) You are able to get both the key and the value so you save resources on calling it again when you want it

2) Like you said, it is 'pythonic' and it is the fastest method there.

Comment: why is it "the fastest here"?